# Adding Class to Default Wordpress Gutenberg Blocks?

Tags: block-editor

I tried to search for the best way to add classes to default Gutenberg blocks and was unable to find anything. What I need to do is add a class that I can target on each default block that Gutenberg comes preinstalled with. So for the blocks that are just paragraph text, headings, etc. I would need to add the same class to all of those blocks.